# XAML DataTrigger for just one grid in Style for multiple grids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have 2 grids which use the same Style. I had to add a DataTrigger where a row is displayed red if a property (from the DataRow) is true.
Unfortunately I only need the DataTrigger on one of those grids. The other grid doesn't even own the property.
I found 2 solutions which feel both dirty:

- Add the property to the grid where its not used/displayed but to prevent the error
- Add another style which is a copy of the first one but has the DataTrigger on top

Is there a way to apply this DataTrigger to just one grid when two grids are effected by the style which contains the DataTrigger?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new style based on the one you already have:

```
<Style x:key="baseStyle>
     <!-- Your current style -->
</Style>

<Style x:Key="newStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResouce baseStyle}">
     <Style.Triggers>
          <!-- Your DataTrigger -->
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then apply baseStyle for one grid and newStyle for the other.